# How to share a file in test files?

Tags: rust, substrate

I have this hierarchy in my substrate pallet:

```
src/
├── lib.rs
├── mock.rs
├── tests.rs
└── common.rs
Cargo.toml
```

My mock.rs and tests.rs need to share some constants and types, so I put those into common.rs.

in my mock.rs and tests.rs:

```
mod common;
use crate::common::{
        TOKEN_TRANSFER_FEE, Balance,
};
```

in my common.rs:

```
pub mod common {
  pub type Balance = u128;

  pub const TOKEN_TRANSFER_FEE: Balance = 1_000;
}
```

then I got these errors:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `common`
  --> pallets/bridge/src/mock.rs:48:1
   |
48 | mod common;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: to create the module `common`, create file "pallets/bridge/src/mock/common.rs" or "pallets/bridge/src/mock/common/mod.rs"

error[E0583]: file not found for module `common`
  --> pallets/bridge/src/tests.rs:36:1
   |
36 | mod common;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: to create the module `common`, create file "pallets/bridge/src/tests/common.rs" or "pallets/bridge/src/tests/common/mod.rs"
```

Is there an easier way to import those constants and types from that shared common file into mock.rs and tests.rs, instead of making mock folder and tests folders?

Comment: Side note, but you usually don't want to use `mod foo` inside `foo.rs`, since this will make two modules - one for the file and one inside the file.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ is much more active for this topic BTW :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `mod` once and in the other files `use`:

**lib**

```
mod common;
mod mock;

fn entry() {
    eprintln!("{}", common::common::TEST);
}
```

**common**

```
pub mod common {
    pub const TEST: &str = "";
}
```

**mock**

```
use crate::common;

fn mock() {
    eprintln!("{}", common::common::TEST);
}
```